# Mediaplayer showing error(1,-2147483648) while playing byteArray

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I am getting some audio streaming data as base64 String, I convert it in byteArray and then write a file locally as mp3 file to play in mediaplayer. But the problem is mediaplayer througing error(1,-2147483648). How to solve this, I tried with many SO posts but nothing works.

```
**what I am trying to do is fetch base64 string save locally and play**.

        val file = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath + "/audioRecording1.mp3"
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        try {
            val output = FileOutputStream(file)
            output.write(mp3SoundByteArray)
            output.close()
            val fis = FileInputStream(file)
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.fd)
            fis.close()
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder().
                setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).
                setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).
                build())
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener {
                mediaPlayer.start()
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener { mediaPlayer, i, i2 ->

                Log.v("","${i,i2}")
                true
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            toast(e.message!!)
        }
```

could you please tell me how to overcome this?

Comment: `then write a file locally as mp3 file to play in mediaplayer.` Ok but that does not match  `while playing byteArray` as it is playing the mp3 file. A corrupted mp3 file? If your mp3 file is no valid mp3 file then you do not ask about a mediap-layer but better how to decode the base64 in order to write a valid mp3 file.

Comment: `getting some audio streaming data as base64 String` That already is veryu strange as that would mean 30% more bytes than original stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue without writing any header. below way.

```
val clipData =android.util.Base64.decode(data,0)
val output = FileOutputStream(file,true)
output.write(clipData)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it seams that you have trouble with file saving

```
 fun saveFile(responseBody: ResponseBody?, pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile: String) {
        val body = responseBody ?: return
        var input: InputStream? = null
        try {
            val uri = Uri.parse(pathWhereYouWantToSaveFile)
            input = body.byteStream()
            val parcelFileDescriptor =
                context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, FileConst.WRITE_MODE)
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor)
            fileOutputStream.use { output ->
                val bufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE.toInt()
                val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                var read: Int
                while (input.read(buffer).also { read = it } != END_OF_FILE) {
                    output.write(buffer, START_OFFSET, read)
                }
                output.flush()
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            logErrorIfDebug(exception)
        } finally {
            input?.close()
        }
    }

const val READ_MODE = "r"
const val WRITE_MODE = "w"
const val START_OFFSET = 0
const val END_OF_FILE = -1
const val BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * BYTES_IN_KILOBYTE
```

Try this in your **viewModel** or **data sourse layer**, then send result to UI layer and use there

Have you checked that your file saved correct? You can go to directory and try to open file. If everything okey, you can get it by uri in your media player.
Also you should check - perhaps you are creating another path for save and retrieve

Better way to use player is https://exoplayer.dev/

But native library also can work with internal uri path.

Comment: Can I play exoPlayer to play byteArray ?

Comment: never tried, it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747416/exoplayer-play-audio-from-byte-array-bytearraydatasource

Comment: okay thanks let me try with that

Answer (score 0):

If you just take a random part of a base64 encoded audio stream then your bytearray will (after decoding) contain a part of an audiofile.

Some audio stream bytes.

Not a complete valid mp3 file with headers and such.

If you had said: `am getting a mp3 file in one base64 String` then your approch would be ok.

Comment: the thing is, I am sending some text to server for TTS purpose, and server respond me with a base64 audio of that text. I need to save that base64 in local storage of the device for playing later.

Comment: That is no reaction to what i commented and answered. And i can do nothing with your info if you do not come to the point.

Comment: TTS? `with a base64 audio of that text. ` Well..... is it a stream? Or is it a valid mp3 file? You are not reacting to what i answered. What is it exactly that you receive base64 encoded?

Comment: its a stream..without any header

Comment: Why would the server send a stream ? Does the server continue to send data? How often do you receive some base64 encoded stuff for one request?

Comment: Cannot the exoplayer just play some audio bytes from a byte array or from an inputstream that delivers that byte array?

Comment: maybe exoPlayer cannot play byteArray.

Comment: That is no answer. I did not ask if you know how to use the exoplayer. I asked if the exoplayer could do it.

Comment: it is stream audio, suppose if I say a sentence then server will return back me the audio in form of base64 string. Now I want to save that as a wav file now so that I can play the file later. and yes the string contains "RIFF" header and others